# How to execute String in mysql and then insert into temp table?

Tags: mysql, select, prepared-statement

I want to insert the results from a dynamic query into a temp table or a way to use this result as a table. 
for example :

```
declare str varchar(2000);
set @str="select 
       from
        `cdr` ";
 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
```

and now i want to execute a query like this

```
 select * from stmt1;
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** Try below Code:

```
DECLARE str VARCHAR(2000);
SET @str="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable1 select * from `cdr` ";
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

SELECT * FROM tempTable1;
-- Code what you want to work on temptable1 
DROP TABLE tempTable1;
```

**Orginal Answer:** First Create Temp Table and then use below code:

```
DECLARE str VARCHAR(2000);
SET @str="insert into tempTable select * from `cdr` ";
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Then you can execute query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tempTable;
```